# jQuery slick.js carousel: add items w/o changing current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using slick carousel http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/.

I have carousel with too many items in it. I want to load it partially in a background mode. I use example code to add new items:

```
$('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div>slide</div>', index);
```

When I load "next" items it works fine, but the problem is to load "previous" items. For example, if current slide index is 10 and I load items on 0 position, carousel will scroll to new item with 10 index. But I need "silent mode" for AJAX requests w/o changing carousel position when I am adding new items.

How can I block slick carousel from changing position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't block changing position, but you can set the position without any animation.

1. Add new items on `afterChange` event
2. When you add new items to carousel, use `$('.add-remove').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide, true);`
3. Calculate `currentSlide` as index of current slide after all new items added